# Can sending a message to someone ask a question, but the question is on hold?

Tags: support

Some days ago I read a question with a smartphone, I thought it was an interesting question and thought about it. When I had the chance to use a PC for testing, I noticed the question was on hold.

In this case if I want to ask the questioner one question to clarify one condition, what can I do since I can not put anything in the question any more?

Comment: When you have 50 reputation points, you will be able to post comments.

Comment: There was nothing you could have done anyway, even if the question had not been closed. An *answer* would have been an inappropriate place to ask a question. If a question cannot be answered without additional clarification, it is rightfully closed. Move on to another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have 50 points, you can add a comment. Even though the question is On Hold.

This may seem restrictive, and there's been some discussion if the threshold for commenting should be lowered. But there should be a threshold - the comment section needs to be protected from spam and mindless chatter.

There is no direct messaging on Stack Exchange. Almost everything we do here is public. This is intentional - it means these things are subject to public scrutiny, which helps to prevent and stop people being abusive.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply.  I know the situation, because I do not have enough reputation to do many things.  I was registered many years ago but lost the account information while moving around then have to register again, and things changed a log during the years.

Comment: And once I saw another question which are related to a seldom used technology, many people do not fully understand it then vote it to on hold.  I can do also nothing in that situation.

Comment: @TigerHwang Maybe you should update your question here. Explain what you'd like to say to the user. With luck, someone here can add a comment on your behalf, if they understand the suggestion well enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I prefer to do more check first.

Answer (score 7):

The user has already been prompted to clarify their question by their question being put on hold. Since you lack commenting privileges, I'm afraid there's not much you can do but wait and hope they clear things up (and the question gets reopened).